# My android app run on emulator but it's not running on real device(samsung galaxy tab 2)

Tags: android

My app work well on my emulator but's not on my samsung galaxy tab 2 i dont understand cause i configure mysql server to GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON. TO  **'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'**;**
**FLUSH PRIVILEGES ;**

**logCat**

```
error in http connection org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnecttException Connection to [http://192.168.1.2:80][1] refused
```

Comment: Did you add the internet permission in the manifest?

Comment: How is your Tab 2 connecting to the network? If it is via WiFi, what is the device's IP address, and can it reach 192.168.1.2 in general?

Comment: would you post you manifeast file

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is a firewall in you pc which the mysql server runs in. The emulater is in the same pc, so the firewall does not take effects.

You'd better add mysql's 3306 port to your server or temporarily stop your firewall and try again.

Comment: Please rate my answer up by click the above arrow of the 0 if it helps. Thank you.

Comment: I dont Understand after i reboot my PC i have same problem
error in http connection org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnecttException Connection to [http://192.168.1.2:80][1] refused
i désable firewall and avast

Comment: Maybe you ip is not fixed, so it is no longer 192.168.1.2. Also, some firewalls and antivirus suits will restore to open after rebooting.

Comment: yes thk for your cooperation i open port to fire wall to result this prblm

Answer (score 0):

When your access database(Mysql) from android mobile you must should add port (3306) or Stop firewall.its will work.
if you not want to Stop firewall then add port " Windows Firewall>Advance Advances settings>Outbound Rules>New Rule"
But
keep in your mind if you put Port " protocol type : TCP " Android mobile will not connect with database you must should select " protocol type : Any ".